# Embedding Apache Superset react components in an angular 6 application

Tags: angular, reactjs, apache-superset

I'm trying to integrate Superset react components in my angular 6 application. I've seen examples of simple react components being integrated successfully but I wanted to know if it would work with more complex components or if such a thing is recommended at all.

superset-ui:
https://github.com/apache-superset/superset-ui/tree/master/packages/superset-ui-chart

Integration example:
https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/4.1.1/ht_use_react_component_in_angular_2.x.html

Comment: Did you manage to embed Apache Superset components / graphics into Angular frontend?

Comment: Any update on this? Im trying the same thing

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95VZBqWljsw&list=PLsC0nE-wJ1I6MGgheo6Y8Co1ahHqWU4HH